# Поворот сетки на произвольный угол

Tags: java

Нарисовать сетку для тестирования монитора. По клику мыши на форме циклически менять цвета линий сетки в порядке: красный, синий, зеленый. Предусмотреть возможность изменения шага сетки. Предусмотреть возможность поворота сетки на произвольный угол.

```
package dialogtest1;

 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.Font;
  import java.awt.Graphics;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;

  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

  import javax.swing.*;


  public class DialogTest1 extends JFrame{
JPanel panSouth;
JPanel panCenter;
JButton but;
JButton but1;
JTextField tf1;
JTextField tf2;
JTextField tf3;
JLabel[] grid;
private int colorIndex = 0;
DialogTest1(){
    super();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700, 700);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panSouth = new JPanel();
    tf1 = new JTextField(5);
    tf2 = new JTextField(5);
    tf3 = new JTextField(5);
    but = new JButton("Change");
    but1 = new JButton("Change1");
    panSouth.add(new JLabel("X: "));
    panSouth.add(tf1);
    panSouth.add(new JLabel("Y: "));
    panSouth.add(tf2);
    panSouth.add(but);
    panSouth.add(new JLabel("*: "));
    panSouth.add(tf3);
     panSouth.add(but1);
    add(panSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        int x;
        int y;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!tf1.getText().isEmpty() && !tf2.getText().isEmpty()){
                x = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
                y = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
                if(panCenter != null) {
  remove(panCenter);
  }
                 //double degreeToRotate = 40.0;

                grid = new JLabel[x*y];
                for (int i = 0; i<grid.length; i++){
                    grid[i] = new JLabel() {
                    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
                        Graphics2D gx = (Graphics2D) g;
                        gx.rotate(Math.toRadians(40), getX() + getWidth() / 2, getY() + getHeight() / 2); 
               super.paintComponent(gx); 
                     } 
                     }; 
                             grid[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
                    panCenter.add(grid[i]);


                }

                add(panCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                revalidate();
            }

            }

    });
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            // Клик
            int x = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
            Color color;

            colorIndex = colorIndex + 1;
            if (colorIndex > 2) {
                colorIndex = 1;
            }
            switch (colorIndex) {

                case 0:color = Color.RED;break;
                case 1:color = Color.BLUE;break;
                case 2:color = Color.GREEN;break;
                default:color = Color.RED;break;
            }

            // System.out.println("mouseClicked ->" + e.getX() + "->" + e.getY());
            for (int i = 0; i<x*y; i++){
                grid[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color));
            }

            repaint();
        }

    });

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DialogTest1().setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно повернуть сетку на заданный угол.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поворачивать с использованием метода `Graphics2D.rotate` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html):

```
double degreeToRotate = 40.0;
panCenter = new JPanel(new GridLayout(y, x))  {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gx = (Graphics2D) g;
        gx.rotate(Math.toRadians(degreeToRotate), getX() + getWidth() / 2, getY() + getHeight() / 2);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
```

Comment: А как мне можно запихнуть в gx grid[i]?
Ведь поворачиваю я сетку, а рисуется она:
     grid = new JLabel[x*y];
                    for (int i = 0; i<grid.length; i++){
                        grid[i] = new JLabel();
                                       grid[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
                        panCenter.add(grid[i]);

Comment: Можно таким же образом переопределить метод в JLabel и поворачивать каждый grid[i]

Comment: А можете пожалуйста подсказать, как переопределить метод в JLabel?

Comment: Можно также - new JLabel()  {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gx = (Graphics2D) g;
        gx.rotate(Math.toRadians(degreeToRotate), getX() + getWidth() / 2, getY() + getHeight() / 2);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}; Но лучше отнаследовать новый класс и в нем переопределить paintComponent

Comment: Добавил переопределение метода в JLabel. Если не трудно, можете пожалуйста посмотреть в чем там ошибка(отредактировал первое сообщение). Сразу хочу извиниться, если в коде что-то глупое, я недолго изучаю java.

Comment: grid[i] = new JLabel() {
                            @Override
                            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                                Graphics2D gx = (Graphics2D) g;
                                gx.rotate(Math.toRadians(40), getX() + getWidth() / 2, getY() + getHeight() / 2);
                                super.paintComponent(g);
                            }
                        };
Но так будут поворачиваться каждый сегменты в отдельности - в итоге получиться не совсем то что вы ожидаете, наверное

Comment: Изменил, как вы написали, но все равно исходную сетку не выводит:( . Не подскажите, в чем ошибка?